# Возникает ошибка java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/awt/geom/Line2D$Float;

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

Работаю над андроид игрушкой и вылазит ошибка

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   [Ljava/awt/geom/Line2D$Float;
>           at com.redromashka.entities.Player.hit(Player.java:151)

Вот кусок кода где ошибка:

```
public void hit()
    {
        if(hit){return;}

        hit = true;

        dx = dy = 0;

        GameSound.stop("thruster");
        left = right = false;

        hitLines = new Line2D.Float[4]; //вот строка где ошибка
        for(int i = 0, j = hitLines.length - 1; i < hitLines.length; j = i++)
        {hitLines[i] = new Line2D.Float(shapex[i], shapey[i], shapex[j], shapey[j]);}

        hitLinesVec = new Point2D.Float[4];
        hitLinesVec[0] = new Point2D.Float(
                MathUtils.cos(radians + 1.5f),
                MathUtils.sin(radians + 1.5f)
        );
        hitLinesVec[1] = new Point2D.Float(
                MathUtils.cos(radians - 1.5f),
                MathUtils.sin(radians - 1.5f)
        );
        hitLinesVec[2] = new Point2D.Float(
                MathUtils.cos(radians - 2.8f),
                MathUtils.sin(radians - 2.8f)
        );
        hitLinesVec[3] = new Point2D.Float(
                MathUtils.cos(radians + 2.8f),
                MathUtils.sin(radians + 2.8f)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Откуда бы в Android взяться AWT? У Android своя графическая библиотека.